# Rooting Linux via mysql

Tags: linux, centos, root, mysql

I have a CentOS 5.6 x86 installed. I have full access to mysql but it seems I have forgotten Linux root password. How I can access the root via MySQL? Is it even possible?
Update: MySQL Version is 5.0.77

Answer (score 1):

I am not a MySQL expert but I don't believe that MySQL allows you to execute arbitrary (shell) commands.

Furthermore MySQL would have to run as root which I hope it doesn't.

So in order to achieve that you would probably need two exploits: One hacking MySQL itself and giving you shell access and another for becoming root: a local root exploit (privilege escalation). You probably don't want to do either of them.

You can easily reset the password by booting the system with the kernel parameter `init=/bin/bash` or by booting from another medium (CD/DVD/USB), chrooting into the installed system and call `passwd` there.

But the whole story seems strange to me. Who does not have SSH access with keys instead of a password?